# How to update one table from another in Symfony

Tags: symfony

Getting an error:

> Variable "form" does not exist in
>   comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod:new.html.twig at line 9

I'm not sure if the update is been done properly but basically i want to update payroll week with payroll period once there's a match. The repository checks for that.

**Repository:**

```
 public function findByPayrollPeriod($startDate, $endDate)
    {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:PayrollWeek
            WHERE startDate = :startDate or endDate = :endDate'
    )
    ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
    ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
    ->getResult();
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);

    //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){

                $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period exist.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {  
           $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findByPayrollPeriod(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);
           if ($payrollweek){
           $entity->setPayrollweek($payrollweek);

           $em->persist($entity);
          // $em->persist($payrollweek);

           $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
       }


  return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView())); 


    }
}
 private function createCreateForm(Payrollperiod $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new PayrollperiodType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

**Twig:**

```
 {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}


{% block body -%}
    <div id="pg_section_sml_card">
        <h1 class="pg_card_hdr">Payroll Period</h1>
  <div class="pg_card_text">

            {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_end(form) }}

        <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('payrollperiod') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
&nbsp;
</div>
    </div>       
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You forgot to close your if payrollweek

Comment: ok thanks, I closed it still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I did to achieve the results.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {


    $entity = new Payrollperiod();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);

        $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());

        //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){
                $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period exist.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }
            //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
           elseif ($payrollweek){
            //This adds the payroll period id to the payroll week table
            foreach($payrollweek as $pWeek) { 
            $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
            //$em->persist($pWeek);
            } 

          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll week was updated.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
             }
             else{
               $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
             }
       }

       //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
       return array(
           'entity' => $entity,
           'form'   => $form->createView(),
       );   

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a valid method called
`createCreateForm()`, then you're not returning a valid Symfony form component to `$form`, you should pass in the form type and entity type as in
`$form = $this-createForm(FormType::class, $entity);`
Where **form type** is the form you're trying to create, can you confirm that's the issue?, and I don't see you rendering anything in `createAction()`

Comment: I have updated the question with the createCreateForm()

Comment: Still doesn't work when I render it unless I did it wrong, I have updated the question with my changes